# Flutter 3.7.12 Internationalization | how to persist and apply locale

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, internationalization

I'm implementing internationalization in Flutter by following: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#loading-and-retrieving-localized-values.

Everything is going fine up to the point that I want to give the users the possibility to change to locale and persist their choice.

All the examples online seem outdated so I'm wondering if anyone can help me out?

in the `main.dart` file I'm trying to use the `SharedPreferences` to retry the choice of the user. But I'm getting async errors.

So the question is: How can I apply the choice of the user while in the application and load it when initializing the Flutter app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than loading in `main.dart` file you can load and store data in your first class initState which is most probably `MyApp.dart`.